# No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I recently released an Android App on the playstore this app is currently linked with both `Google's Admob` and `Google's firebase for analytics`, after a while I started working on an update that includes `FIREBASE NOTIFICATIONS` when I tried to connect firebase to the project I got this error:

> Firebase
>               No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project for the following reasons:
>
> An app with this package name and SHA1 is already connected to a Google project. If you have used a Google API previously, please select that project in the Connect to an existing project list.
>
> Client Package Name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Client SHA1: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

How to fix this **without** loosing my previous analytics stats ?

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use The existing App And Include Feature For Push Notifications at Firebase console or  firebase assistant in studio 
As you are creating a new project  in firebase assistant for push notifications but you have aldready added this app for another services it Wont use two firebase projects for Single application so Make Sure You Are Going With The Past Project which you have done for admob and then go to cloud messaging amd enable it then you will successfully connect

If any errors again i can Help 
Thank you

And If You Created Aldready you can import that project into previous project but make sure that you use same firebase account

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/
Use this link to know about importing projects